# Is this an answer?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, specific-answer

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7055754) answer in the low quality posts review queue. The user is deleted, and following the link to the question shows that the answer isn't there. Presumably, then is an audit and I will pass by hitting "Recommend deletion". With that said, though, the first part of the answer appears to be perfectly valid (at least to me, an admittedly less than experienced user of JavaScript). The second part (where he links to a blog) is clearly spam and should be removed, but does that warrant removing the entire post instead of just the link?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[The answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28132454/revisions) consists of two parts.

[image]

1. A code sample with a suggestion to the user
2. Blogspam

The codesnippet was copy-pasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24857280/1864167). There are no redeeming qualities in this answer.

Comment: I had not noticed that it was a copy-paste. That makes the question moot I guess.

Comment: Seems like an ambiguous audit since from the audit screen we can't easily determine the fact that it was copied.

Comment: That answer can be deleted too if you ask me... a chunk of code with _"try this"_ Thank you joe!

Comment: As usual, just because a post was deleted by a moderator, it doesn't necessarily mean it will make an ideal review audit. Unfortunately, SO doesn't care about fixing the broken review audits. They are busy implementing more important things, like hats.

Comment: @Lundin great example of logical fallacy. Hats were there waaaay before audits even existed, so implementing them didn't really take the devs any time from fixing the audits. Instead of whining you should really propose an algorithm to read the mind of moderators. Then you can whine if they do not implement it.

Comment: @nico: Why not just ask the mod when they delete?  Does everything really need to be an algorithm?

Comment: @Kevin 100% agree with you. Mine was just a jestful remark to the other comment saying that the review audits are broken because some bad examples "slip through" the current algorithm. I am not expecting anyone to come up with a mind-reading algorithm.